# npm meanio install failure

Tags: node.js, macos, mean.io

I'm trying to make an openshift MEAN stack application. I'm running `npm install -g meanio`
however it keeps throwing the following NPM errors:

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12

npm ERR! No version provided in package.json
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "meanio"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! meanio@0.8.83 postinstall: `cd ./lib/core_modules/server && npm install && cd ../../..`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the meanio@0.8.83 postinstall script 'cd ./lib/core_modules/server && npm install && cd ../../..'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the meanio package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cd ./lib/core_modules/server && npm install && cd ../../..
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meanio
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Any help or questions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to create MEAN app is via `mean-cli`

```
$ npm install -g mean-cli
$ mean init <myApp>
$ cd <myApp> && npm install
```

Make sure you have prerequisites installed.
http://learn.mean.io/